# Android RTL layout direction align center issue

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, arabic, right-to-left

I'm developing an Android App that needs to be support Arabic language. (Which should be read from Right To Left). After quick googled the solutions, I figure out android fully support Arabic language natively in API level 17 with the declaration of

> android:supportsRtl="true"

in the application tag inside of the AndroidManifest so that I can use the layout mirroring to automatically flip the layout for better right to left reading experience. However, I've noticed there is an issue happening while I use centerInParent in a view that inside of a sub RelativeLayout during the layout mirroring. Below are my codes and expected layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/shape_flag_imageview_boarder"
        android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text here bla bla bla"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Normal Left to Right Layout]

Image above showing the expected result in normal layout direction which is Left to Right. The purpose I wrap the ImageView and ProgressBar together in a sub view is because I want the ProgressBar showing in the middle of the ImageView while the image is loading from the internet. After the I've changed Locale to Arabic, it becomes like
[image: Layout out in RTL]
As I've try and error and figure out that this is causing by the centerInParent of the ProgressBar. It instead of centering inside the sub view, it align center to the root parent view which is the most outer RelativeLayout. Below is the screen shot of removing centerInParent code from the ProgressBar.

[image]

It clearly shows the layout mirroring works good, but the ProgressBar position is not what I'm expected. So I've try to work on centerVertical and centerHorizontal, the result are shown in images below respectively.
[image]
[image]

None of the solutions works, and none of the topic I've searched related to this issue. So I guess this might be a bug from Android library? If anyone knows the issues or solutions, please share to me. Thanks

Comment: At least part of your problem is you aren't specifying where anything should go fully-  nothing in the outer relative layout is aligned to anything in the parent.  So I'm not surprised it isn't figuring out how to lay it out correctly.

Comment: the parent RelativeLayout inside which you're positioning progressbar, doesn't have fixed height and width. so that may lead you to undesired results.

Comment: @GabeSechan In shorts, the Left to Right layout showing above is what I've expected, and I expect it looks exactly the same but flipped into Right to Left in Arabic locale. I did not used any Left or Right alignment but instead I used Start and End, so I expect it to works fine, but it doesn't.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I've try to put a fixed height and width in that RelativeLayout, it surprisingly works. But I like it to be wrap content instead of putting fixed height and width due to the ImageView might be vary sizes, it determined during run time. Plus, why is that RelativeLayout that I put the progressbar works only in LTR but not RTL?

Comment: I don't know why is it not working in case of `RTL` only. But it shouldn't work in case of `LTR` as well. Because this is how `RelativeLayout` works. We put every view relative to other views inside `RelativeLayout`, and in that case it should have fixed height and width.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Totally wrong.  A RelativeLayout does NOT need a fixed size.  It rarely has one in fact.  But if you don't have all of the subviews well defined to align to either center or a side (or to relative to another view that is) you can have odd results.

Comment: Have you try to set `android:gravity="center"` in ProgressBar?

Comment: @GabeSechan I am sorry, But I'll be disagreed with you. Because what I said is correct anyway. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM. And I am not saying on my own, you might want to check document reference here -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I've been doing it for the past 6 years.  You're just wrong.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Also, what it says is you can't have a circular dependency between items (which is totally correct).  That's why you can't do that particular combination.  Not that you can't have a wrap_content relative layout, which is totally normal.

Comment: You can have wrap-content to RelativeLayout. But it works more perfectly when you want to put any view relative to parent layout and parent layout have fixed height and width. ^^ @GabeSechan

Comment: @rekire He isn't right.  He may have solved this problem, but I have dozens of apps with wrap_content RelativeLayouts.  He is NOT right that you can't have one of those.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it by adding `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` into the child RelativeLayout. Basically, it deactivates the RTL formatting for this particular RelativeLayout, and the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` behaves correctly again. It solves our particular issue as our particular RelativeLayout contains only centred elements. But this trick should not be used if the Layout contains other elements which have to support correctly RTL, like text views for example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is an RTL layout bug in the Android framework, which **only affects Android 4.2 specifically (API 17)** and when android:supportsRtl="true" is enabled in AndroidManifest.xml.

It happens when you use a **RelativeLayout** that contains items positioned with **`android:layout_centerVertical="true"`** or **`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`**.

You can fix it in Java code like this:

```
View relativeLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_relative_layout, parent, false);

// Fix RTL layout bug on Android 4.2 (for Arabic and Hebrew mode)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 17 &&
       getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
     // Force a left-to-right layout
     relativeLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

let me tell you correct answer, look your RelativeLayout(id:imageLayout),it's width is wrap_content, and your ProgressBar(id:progressbar) add an attribute android:layout_centerInParent="true".It means parent not limit witdh,and child also want to center,so parent will be stretched.

Comment: This worked for me, I've to specify the width of Relative layout